# How to run topcoder arena applet using proxy in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, java, proxy, icedtea

I was trying to run topcoder arena applet using proxy. I install latest JDK and iced-tea. 
When I try to run using:

```
javaws ContestAppletProd.jnlp
```

I'm getting:

```
File cannot be launched because offline-allowed tag not specified and system currently offline.
```

I tried setting proxy in icedtea applet but still getting the same error.

Comment: I am getting the same error as you, please say if u did find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Configure proxy settings in icedtea control panel. Search for icedtea in dash to get the control panel, then set the proxy settings in network category on left.